# Are the rings $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}^3$ isomorphic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-isomorphism

Are the rings $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}^3$ isomorphic, where $\mathbb{R}^2=\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ is the set of all pairs $(a,b)$ with $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$, and $\mathbb{R}^3=\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ is the set of all triples $(a,b,c)$ with $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$, using component wise addition and multiplication?

Comment: What are your thoughts on this matter?

Comment: What happens when $R$ is finite?

Comment: What is the definition of isomorphic for a pair of rings? How might the extra degree of freedom of $R^3$ contradict that definition?

Comment: @D_S If its finite than R^3>R^2. I do not see how this helps however, since both rings are infinite. Can I still prove some how that R^2<R^3?

Comment: @MJD  I thought they were isomorphic because each ring is an infinite ring, and I think that would allow it to be surjective. Also it meets the requirement that f(a+b)=f(a)+f(b), as well as f(ab)=f(a)f(b). I do not know how to show that it is or isn't injective.

Comment: What is the "it" that you refer to in your last comment? You have some specific function $f$ in mind which is surjective and satisfies the requirements $f(a+b)=f(a)+f(b)$ and $f(ab)=f(a)f(b)$ but you don't know if it's injective or not? **What is it?**

Comment: When you say "I thought they were isomorphic because each ring is an infinite ring", are you saying that all infinite rings are isomorphic?

Comment: @bof No, I do not have a specific function in mind. I also do not think that all infinite rings are isomorphic. Maybe, what is throwing me off is I do not understand what it is meant by defining $\mathbb{R}^3=\mathbb{R}+\mathbb{R}+\mathbb{R}$ while it is also the set of all (a,b,c) where $a,b,c ∈ \mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 5):

Consider idempotents in each ring, that is solutions of $e^2=e$. In your
first ring you are solving $(a^2,b^2)=(a,b)$, and in the second, $(a^2,b^2,c^2)=(a,b,c)$. How may solutions have you in each case?

Comment: For $\mathbb{R}^2$ would you have $\infty^2$ solutions and for $\mathbb{R}$ you would have $\infty^3$ solutions, and since $\infty^2<\infty^3$ then $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}^3$ are not isomorphic?

Comment: @JM23:  think again, por favor:  if $(a^2,  b^2) = (a,  b)$, then $a^2 = a$, $b^2 = b$.  Since $a, b \in \Bbb R$, the solutions are $a = 0, 1 = b$.  There are thus $4$ idempotents in $\Bbb R^2$ *und so weiter* . . .

Answer (score 0):

**HINT.** If they are going to be isomorphic, it should work for any ring. Think of the special case where the ring is actually a field, i.e. $R=\mathbb{k}$. Can you think of some theorems from basic Linear Algebra to say whether or not the rings $R^2=\mathbb{k}^2$ and $R^3=\mathbb{k}^3$ are isomorphic? Maybe focus on the only difference between them...